# How many minds exist within the Holy Trinity?

Tags: trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, mind-of-god

Normally I would hear the answer is one mind, but I was wondering; If beliefs are part of your mind, and since Jesus (the second person) would believe "I am the Son of God" and the Father would believe "I am the Father", They would believe two different things i.e, The Son would not believe He is the Father but the Father would believe He is the Father.

Shouldn't that mean the Trinity should have three minds (for each conciseness/person) and one will?

Comment: Questions such as this risked being closed as opinion-based unless they specify whether one is speaking of Orthodox (traditional) Christianity or various others.

Comment: I am speaking of trinitarian Christianity,

Comment: We've had several questions on this topic before, including one that this is a direct duplicate of. Unfortunately most answers to that question do not represent the historical Nicene/Chalcedonian position, that the three persons share the one faculty of mind. But I guess that represents the fact that over church history there has been much less consistency on this question that there has been for other aspects of Trinitarian theology. Rather than asking how many exist, it would probably be better to ask for the arguments for one mind or for three minds, and then they can make their case.